# How to make toon shader more realistic and clean crooked shadow in models?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

How can I make my toon shader more realistic? I have a crooked shadow in my character model, how can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: Made sure you turned on full oversampling for all toon materials?

Comment: I am not sure if you have seen this. It's a keynote from 2016's Blender Conference talking specifically about ideas for toon shading. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pStNSM_h_LY&t=912s Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that might help is to bump up the subdivision modifier (assuming you have it on), though that might increase render times.

[Another thing you might try is custom normals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSlud8DFXEk). This way, you can have more control over how the shading looks but it adds several steps to your workflow.

[I would also suggest this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhGjCzxJV3E). Its long and has nothing to do with blender, but it is very informative.